# High CPU load delaying UIView redraw (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es

I'm making an iOS app with an OpenGL ES view. On top of the 3D view I draw miscellaneous GUI bits using Cocoa Touch.

This works fine as long as the framerate is good. However, when the CPU load gets to high (GLES view drops to 20-ish FPS), it seems like the next UIKit display cycle is being pushed forward.

Specifically, I'm trying to display a tooltip view, based on various UIView subclasses. When it's time to display it, I update the tooltip label text and resize its background, then set hidden to NO for the main UIView and call setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout.

When the framerate is low (i.e. CPU load is high), the next display cycle seems to be pushed forward indefinitely. But immediately when the CPU load goes down, the view is displayed as expected.

Is there any way I can instigate a draw cycle in UIKit between my 3D engine redraws? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, all applications do their UI drawing and logic on one thread, unless otherwise specified.

You could move your 3D drawing code into another thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(3DRenderingMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
```

Here's the relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: All logic and drawing running in one thread (which they do in my app) is fine. Point is, high CPU loads seem to push forward UIKit redraws indefinitely, even though I'm definitely not blocking the main thread. UIKit seems to purposefully skip redrawing when CPU load is high; This is what I want to prevent in specific cases.